# Complexity of std::count

Tags: c++, stl, time-complexity

I was in some online code quiz website where there is a complexity restriction that the code should not exceed **O(N)** in both time and memory where **N** is the size of the vector `A`. My code was exactly (Full Code):

```
int foo(int X, const std::vector<int> &A) {
    auto N = A.size();
    auto total_hit = std::count(A.cbegin(), A.cend(), X);
    auto K = N - total_hit;
    if (K < 0 || K >= N){
        return -1;
    }
    return K;
}
```

I got a result that I exceed the time complexity. Is there any possibility rather than they are wrong?

Comment: Is this the full code?  Or do you have code not shown?

Comment: Full code.. I do not have to write the main function

Comment: What does exact message/question in this online code quiz? Could you please provide a link?

Comment: @VadimKey Unfortunately the agreement tells that I should not spread it in any way.

Comment: [OT]: I don't see how K be negative.

Comment: @Jarod42 yup you are right. I was just  in hurry.

Comment: @Jarod42 or strictly greater than `N`, forthat matter :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count):

> **Complexity**: exactly last - first comparisons / applications of the predicate

they are wrong!

And [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/) agrees:

> **Complexity**: Linear in the distance between first and last: Compares once each element.

---

Of course, the complexity of [std::cbegin()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/cbegin/), [std::cend()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/cend/) and [std::vector::size()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size#Complexity) is **constant**.

---

<sub>If I were you, I would contact the site, linking them to this question.</sub>